# Euler function - all values of n give $\phi(n)=10$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

How do I find the equation that will give me the result for $\phi (n)=10$ and find any possible values of $n$ that works?

Comment: Why do you believe there is an equation that will do this?

Comment: I think there is no formula to get that (as Chris Eagle says). However, you can just look at the graph http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:EulerPhi.svg to get what you want

Comment: actually I think that there may be .. not sure

Comment: @AlanSimonin thank you but I dont need just the values but also a way...

Comment: Well you can use the properties of the Euler's totient function : if $n$ is prime, then $\phi (n) = n-1$, so $n=11$. Then you can use the fact that if $n=p_1^{k_1} \cdots p_n^{k_n}$ then $\phi(n) = \phi(p_1^{k_1}) \cdots \phi(p_n^{k_n})$ and try the values of the divisors of 10...

Comment: In addition to the answers below, this answer may be helpful http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265397/inversion-of-the-euler-totient-function/265700#265700. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\phi(n)=n\prod_{p|n}(1-\cfrac 1 p) =\cfrac n {p_1p_2p_3p_4\dots}(p_1-1)(p_2-1)(p_3-1)(p_4-1) \dots$$

(for the distinct prime factors $p_i$ of $n$).

Now note that the fraction on the right hand side of the expression is an integer, so that $(p_i-1)$ must be a factor of 10, and this restricts the options. Then also observe that you need a factor 5 from somewhere, but if n were a multiple of 5 you'd get $\phi(n)$ being a multiple of 4 - so where is the 5 to come from? That should restrict the options enough to work things out pretty easily.

Answer (score 5):

Note that if $n=\prod_p p^{e_p}$ then  $$\phi(n)=\prod_{e_p\ge1}(p-1)p^{e_p-1}.$$
Each factor must be $\le 10$ and in fact a divisor of $10$.
This excludes all primes $p>11$.
Also, $p=7$ is excluded ($p-1$ is a multiple of $3$), and so is $p=5$ ($p-1$ is a multiple of $4$).
Since at least one factor must be a multiple of $5$, we conclude therefore that $p=11$ occurs. To make its contribution $\le 10$, we must have $e_{11}=1$; but that already makes $(11-1)11^0=10$, so all other factors must equal $1$.
Thus $3$ cannot occur as it would contribute at least $3-1=2$. 
However, $2$ can occur, but only with $e_2=1$.
Thus we find that $\phi(n)=10$ implies
$$n=11\text{ or }n=22.$$

Comment: How do we prove that these are the only numbers that n can obtain?