# Solve for $m\in\mathbb{N}$ the equation $\phi (m)=12$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

> Solve for $m\in\mathbb{N}$ the equation $\phi (m)=12$

I found (by trial) $m=\{13,21,26,28,36\}$, but do not know if misinterpreted the problem, but actually I suppose I have to find an equation that generates these values​​? is how? Is there a way to solve $\phi(m)=k$, with $k\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Edited, tank you.

Comment: @PabloRotondo Directions to this inequality? And how to apply it in problem?

Comment: @PabloRotondo The inequality is valid $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: I see what the problem was, it should be $n^2 \geq \varphi(n)\sigma(n) \geq \frac{6 n^2}{\pi^2}$. And so we get
$$ \varphi(n) \geq \frac{6n / \pi^2}{\log(n) + 1} $$ this means we don't have to check for $n> 113$, of course, that's not something you'd do by hand.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270936/euler-function-all-values-of-n-give-phin-10

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23947/how-to-solve-the-equation-phin-k.

Answer (score 3):

**Remark 1:** If $p$ is a prime $p|n$ then $p-1|12$. This shows that the only primes which could divide $n$ are $\{ 2, 3, 5, 7, 13 \}$.

**Remark 2:** If $p^2|n$ then $p(p-1)|12$. This shows that $5^2 \nmid n, 7^2 \nmid n$ and $13^2 \nmid n$.

Now we go systematically through all prime factors , starting from the biggest.

**Case 1:** $13|n$. Then $n=13m$ with $13 \nmid m$. Then

$$12=\phi(13m)=\phi(13) \phi(m)=12 \phi (m) \Rightarrow \phi(m)=1 \,.$$
There are only $2$ values $m$ can take.

**Case 2:** $7|n, 13 \nmid m$. Then $n=7m$ with $7 \nmid m$. Then
$$12=\phi(7m)=\phi(7) \phi(m)=6 \phi (m) \Rightarrow \phi(m)=2 \,.$$
There are only $3$ values $m$ can take.

**Case 3:** $5|n, 7 \nmid m, 13 \nmid m$. Then $n=5m$ with $5 \nmid m$. Then
$$12=\phi(5m)=\phi(5) \phi(m)=4 \phi (m) \Rightarrow \phi(m)=3 \,.$$
But this is not possible (why?)

**Case 4:** $5\nmid n, 7 \nmid m, 13 \nmid m$. Then 
$$n=2^a3^b$$

Now break the problem in three subcases, eacn being easy to solve:

*Subcase 1:* $a=0$. In this case $n=3^b$ and 
$$12= \phi(3^b)=2\cdot 3^{b-1} \,.$$
no solution.

*Subcase 2:* $b=0$. In this case $n=2^a$ and 
$$12= \phi(2^a)= 2^{a-1} \,.$$
no solution.

*Subcase 3:* $a\neq 0, b\neq 0$. In this case
$$12= \phi(2^a3^b)=2\cdot 2^{a-1}3^{b-1} \,.$$
There is one solution in this case..

Answer (score 0):

Hints: we have that

$$12=\varphi(m)=m\prod_{p\mid m,\,p\;\text{prime}}\left(1-\frac1p\right)$$

Observe that the above seriously limits the number and kind of primes factors $\;m\;$ can have...

Comment: Yes, but I can not build, see: $$m\prod_{p\mid m}{\left(1-\frac{1}{p} \right)}=12$$ and?

Comment: Sure you can. 12 only as so many divisors: 1,2,3,6, and 12. First find what prime powers give you these after taking $\phi(p^n)$, and then use multiplicativity to put them together.

Comment: Oops: missed $4$ in my list of factors.

Comment: The above means $$m\prod(p-1)=12\prod p$$

and among other things we deduce that $\;p-1\mid 12\;$ for every prime factor of $\;m\;$ , which means $\;p-1\in\{1,2,4,6,12\}\iff p\in\{2,3,5,7,13\}\;$ . 

Using that also $\;m=\prod p^{a_p}\;$ , we get that $\;\prod p^{a_p-1}\prod(p-1)=12\;$ and etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a formula : if $m=p^a*q^b*...$ then $\phi(m) = (p-1)*p^{a-1}*(q-1)*q^{b-1}*...$

Comment: Yes, but I can not build, see:
$$12=(p-1)\cdot p^{a-1}\cdot(q-1)\cdot q^{b-1}\cdot\;\;...$$

Comment: prime factors of 12 or 2 and 3, so p or p-1 is 2 or 3 for every p dividing m. You can go manually from here, what do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

A small remark. If $\phi (m) = n$ and $m$ is odd, then $\phi (2m) = n$. Hence $42$ should be in your list.

Answer (score 0):

You have $\psi (m )=12$ and you have $$12=\psi(m)=m~\large \Pi_{p | m}\big(\frac{ p - 1}{p}\big)$$

So, each $p$ which divides $m$ should be such that $p-1$ divides $12$.(There is a gap and it would be your responsibility to verify this).

So, what are all primes $p$ such that $p-1$ divides $12$.

It would not take much time to see that only possible $p$ are ??? (Do not look at the spoiler box)

> $p\in \{2,3,5,7,13\} $

We are not yet sure if all these primes divide $m$,

It would be your turn to check possible values of $m$

- Suppose $2$ is only factor of $m$ then $m=?$
- Suppose $3$ is only factor of $m$ then $m=?$
- Suppose $5$ is only factor of $m$ then $m=?$
- Suppose $7$ is only factor of $m$ then $m=?$
- Suppose $13$ is only factor of $m$ then $m=?$

you should check all other possibilities taking two at a time,taking three at a time and so on..

I am sure you would be convinced just after few steps that you can neglect some cases easily..

Comment: What $p-1\mid 12$?

Comment: you have to find what $p-1$ divides $12$....