# Equations with Euler's Totient Function

Tags: number-theory, totient-function

I understand the totient function, but I am struggling to figure out how to do the process in reverse.

For example, calculating $\phi(n)$ for $n = 240$ is fairly straightforward; I can simply take the prime factorization of the $n$ and use it to solve for the result: $\phi(240) = 64$. However, solving for all $n$ when $\phi(n) = 12$ seems to be much less formulaic. Is there a process for solving "in reverse" this way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [inversion of the Euler totient function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265397/inversion-of-the-euler-totient-function)

Comment: If prime $p$ divides $n,p-1$ must divide $\phi(n)$

Comment: @KeeferRowan That definitely helps narrow the range. Is the only option once I find that range of possible values to proceed by exhaustion?

Comment: I believe so. Not every function has an easy to compute inverse. Since we are working with integers, being able to bound are possibilities within a certain range allows us to get a definite answer by direct computation, e.g. using a computer.