# Finding a solution to a congruence using Eulers Theorem

Tags: number-theory

Suppose $\phi(m) = 1000$, and I wanted to find a number $a$ thats less then $2000$ that is not divisible by $7$ and satisfies $a \equiv 7^{3003}$ (mod $m$). What would be a solution to this and how could I do it without using a calculator?

I know that Eulers Theorem would tell us that $7^{1000} = 1$ (mod $m$) but I do not know how to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly easy to prove that $7 \not \mid m$, using that $\phi(m) = 1000$. Now you have from the Euler's Theorem:

$$7^{1000} \equiv 1 \pmod m$$

Use this in the other congruence relation:

$$a \equiv 7^{ 3003} \equiv 7^{1000} \cdot 7^{1000} \cdot 7^{1000} \cdot 7^{3} \equiv 7^3 \pmod m$$

And you'll end up with:

$$a = km + 343$$

Now since $7 \not \mid a$, we have that $k\ge1$. Also you want to have $a<2000$, so now since $m\ge \phi(m)$ we have:

$$2000 > a = km + 343 \ge k\phi(m) + 343 \ge 1000k$$

From this we have that $k=1$. So you have $a=m+343$ and using the inequality $2000 > a = m+343 \implies m<1657$. And according to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77425/finding-the-maximum-number-with-a-certain-eulers-totient-value/) there are 3 numbers $m$ such that $m<1657$ and $\phi(m) =1000$ and those numbers are: $m=\{1111,1255,1375\}$. So you have 3 possible answers for $a = \{1454,1598,1718\}$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**
$$7^{3003} = 7^3\cdot 7^{3000} = 7^3\cdot \left(7^{1000}\right)^3$$

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there!

You just have to begin to think about what $7^{3003}$ is in terms of $7^{1000}$.

Answer (score 0):

By Euler's theorem $7^3\equiv7^{3003}\equiv a \ mod(m)$ then $a=7^3+km$ now note that $7|a$ iff $7 |k$, because $ \phi(7)=6$ don't divides $\phi(m)=1000$